# Node MySQL complex query

Tags: mysql, node.js

My posts table in MySQ is structured like this:

```
id | title    | parentid
------------------------
1  | title 1  |   55
2  | title 2  |   55
3  | title 3  |   55
4  | title 4  |   1
5  | title 5  |   1
6  | title 6  |   1
7  | title 7  |   1
8  | title 8  |   1
9  | title 9  |   2
10 | title 10 |   2
11 | title 11 |   2
12 | title 12 |   1
13 | title 12 |   2
14 | title 12 |   2
15 | title 12 |   3
16 | title 12 |   1
17 | title 12 |   3
18 | title 12 |   2
19 | title 12 |   3
20 | title 12 |   1
21 | title 12 |   2
```

From Node I query:

```
app.get('/getposts', function(req, res){

    const total = '',

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE parentid = 55", function (err, rows){

        if(rows.length) {
            total = rows.length    // <= Set Value for total posts.

            connection.query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE parentid = 55 LIMIT 3", function (err, newrows){

            if(newrows.length) {

                if(newrows.length < total ){

                    var moreData = "Available";

                    var toSend = {newrows:newrows, moreData:moreData};

                    res.send(toSend) // <= Top 3 rows will be returned.

                }

                else{
                    res.send(newrows)   // <= Top 3 rows will be returned.
                }

            }

            })
        }
        else {
        res.send("NO DATA")
        }
    });
 });
```

This will give me the first 3 rows. Now, based on the rows returned, I want to fetch more data, where the `parentid` is equal to the returned `rows.id`.

So here, after applying the `LIMIT = 3` all the rows with `parentid=55` are to be returned and rows with their `parentid = returnedRows.id` also should be returned along with `moreData` value. I can bind `moreData` in the response as mentioned, just not able to construct the query to pull more data based on the `id` of the `newrows` in 2nd query.

Please help. Many thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Paginate? show some results and let the user know there's more?

Comment: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/php/developing-a-discussion-forum-in-php-with-recursion/

Comment: @yBrodsky yes .. exactly.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you use some ORM. Like Sequelize http://docs.sequelizejs.com/

Anyhow, what you have to do is count, limit and offset. So....

```
//this variables you will get from the front and will need to be sanitized. This is merely an example.
let pageSize = 10, offset = 0
connection.query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM posts WHERE parent_id = 55", (err, total) => {
  connection.query(`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE parent_id = 55 LIMIT ${pageSize}, ${offset}`, (err, results) => {
    return res.send({total, results});
  })
})
```

As you see, this is messy, and has to be complemented with a frontend that requests the right page and the offset, and also lets the user know there's more results based on the `total`. As I said, I recommend you use some ORM, sequelize works like a charm.

Comment: This will return only the rows with `parent_id = 55`, from the returned rows (`results`), the id (lets call it `results.id`) should be used here and query the table again for rows where `parent_id = results.id`. So I am thinking that I need to use a `for loop` somewhere. How do I do it? Checking sequelize, thanks for referring it.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to do. Looks like you need to do a JOIN